# How to compress a data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Before I start: Sorry for the title of the question. I don't know how I can express the problem in one sentence.

I'm working on a big dataset and now I want to merge the good governance indicators from the World Bank into my main data.frame. The data format from the World Bank is not really nice to handle for merging. So, I only want the indicator for few years.

I used this code (I shortened the code a bit):

```
gg_stack <- read.csv("WGIData.csv", sep= ",") 
dput(head(gg_stack, 10))
```

Input:

```
> dput(head(gg_stack, 10))
structure(list(Country.Name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", 
"American Samoa", "Andorra", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antigua and Barbuda", 
"Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", 
"Bahamas, The", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", 
"Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", 
"Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "Brunei Darussalam", 
"Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cabo Verde", "Cambodia", 
"Cameroon", "Canada", "Cayman Islands", "Central African Republic", 
"Chad", "Chile", "China", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo, Dem. Rep.", 
"Congo, Rep.", "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", "Cote d'Ivoire", 
"Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Djibouti", 
"Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "Egypt, Arab Rep.", 
"El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", 
"Fiji", "Finland", "France", "French Guiana", "Gabon", "Gambia, The", 
"Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", 
"Guam", "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", 
"Honduras", "Hong Kong SAR, China", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", 
"Indonesia", "Iran, Islamic Rep.", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", 
"Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jersey, Channel Islands", "Jordan", 
"Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Korea, Dem. People’s Rep.", 
"Korea, Rep.", "Kosovo", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyz Republic", "Lao PDR", 
"Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", 
"Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macao SAR, China", "Macedonia, FYR", 
"Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", 
"Marshall Islands", "Martinique", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", 
"Mexico", "Micronesia, Fed. Sts.", "Moldova", "Monaco", "Mongolia", 
"Montenegro", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia", 
"Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "Netherlands Antilles", "New Zealand", 
"Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Niue", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", 
"Palau", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", 
"Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar", "Reunion", "Romania", 
"Russian Federation", "Rwanda", "Samoa", "San Marino", "Sao Tome and Principe", 
"Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", 
"Singapore", "Slovak Republic", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands", 
"Somalia", "South Africa", "South Sudan", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", 
"St. Kitts and Nevis", "St. Lucia", "St. Vincent and the Grenadines", 
"Sudan", "Suriname", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syrian Arab Republic", 
"Taiwan, China", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "Timor-Leste", 
"Togo", "Tonga", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey", 
"Turkmenistan", "Tuvalu", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", 
"United Kingdom", "United States", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", 
"Venezuela, RB", "Vietnam", "Virgin Islands (U.S.)", "West Bank and Gaza", 
"Yemen, Rep.", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"), class = "factor"), Country.Code = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("ABW", "AFG", 
"AGO", "AIA", "ALB", "AND", "ANT", "ARE", "ARG", "ARM", "ASM", 
"ATG", "AUS", "AUT", "AZE", "BDI", "BEL", "BEN", "BFA", "BGD", 
"BGR", "BHR", "BHS", "BIH", "BLR", "BLZ", "BMU", "BOL", "BRA", 
"BRB", "BRN", "BTN", "BWA", "CAF", "CAN", "CHE", "CHL", "CHN", 
"CIV", "CMR", "COD", "COG", "COK", "COL", "COM", "CPV", "CRI", 
"CUB", "CYM", "CYP", "CZE", "DEU", "DJI", "DMA", "DNK", "DOM", 
"DZA", "ECU", "EGY", "ERI", "ESP", "EST", "ETH", "FIN", "FJI", 
"FRA", "FSM", "GAB", "GBR", "GEO", "GHA", "GIN", "GMB", "GNB", 
"GNQ", "GRC", "GRD", "GRL", "GTM", "GUF", "GUM", "GUY", "HKG", 
"HND", "HRV", "HTI", "HUN", "IDN", "IND", "IRL", "IRN", "IRQ", 
"ISL", "ISR", "ITA", "JAM", "JEY", "JOR", "JPN", "KAZ", "KEN", 
"KGZ", "KHM", "KIR", "KNA", "KOR", "KWT", "LAO", "LBN", "LBR", 
"LBY", "LCA", "LIE", "LKA", "LSO", "LTU", "LUX", "LVA", "MAC", 
"MAR", "MCO", "MDA", "MDG", "MDV", "MEX", "MHL", "MKD", "MLI", 
"MLT", "MMR", "MNE", "MNG", "MOZ", "MRT", "MTQ", "MUS", "MWI", 
"MYS", "NAM", "NER", "NGA", "NIC", "NIU", "NLD", "NOR", "NPL", 
"NRU", "NZL", "OMN", "PAK", "PAN", "PER", "PHL", "PLW", "PNG", 
"POL", "PRI", "PRK", "PRT", "PRY", "PSE", "QAT", "REU", "ROU", 
"RUS", "RWA", "SAU", "SDN", "SEN", "SGP", "SLB", "SLE", "SLV", 
"SMR", "SOM", "SRB", "SSD", "STP", "SUR", "SVK", "SVN", "SWE", 
"SWZ", "SYC", "SYR", "TCD", "TGO", "THA", "TJK", "TKM", "TLS", 
"TON", "TTO", "TUN", "TUR", "TUV", "TWN", "TZA", "UGA", "UKR", 
"URY", "USA", "UZB", "VCT", "VEN", "VIR", "VNM", "VUT", "WSM", 
"XKX", "YEM", "ZAF", "ZMB", "ZWE"), class = "factor"), Indicator.Name = structure(1:10, .Label = c("Control of Corruption: Estimate", 
"Control of Corruption: Number of Sources", "Control of Corruption: Percentile Rank", 
"Control of Corruption: Percentile Rank, Lower Bound of 90% Confidence Interval", 
"Control of Corruption: Percentile Rank, Upper Bound of 90% Confidence Interval", 
"Control of Corruption: Standard Error", "Government Effectiveness: Estimate", 
"Government Effectiveness: Number of Sources", "Government Effectiveness: Percentile Rank", 
"Government Effectiveness: Percentile Rank, Lower Bound of 90% Confidence Interval", 
"Government Effectiveness: Percentile Rank, Upper Bound of 90% Confidence Interval", 
"Government Effectiveness: Standard Error", "Political Stability and Absence of Violence/Terrorism: Estimate", 
"Political Stability and Absence of Violence/Terrorism: Number of Sources", 
"Political Stability and Absence of Violence/Terrorism: Percentile Rank", 
"Political Stability and Absence of Violence/Terrorism: Percentile Rank, Lower Bound of 90% Confidence Interval", 
"Political Stability and Absence of Violence/Terrorism: Percentile Rank, Upper Bound of 90% Confidence Interval", 
"Political Stability and Absence of Violence/Terrorism: Standard Error", 
"Regulatory Quality: Estimate", "Regulatory Quality: Number of Sources", 
"Regulatory Quality: Percentile Rank", "Regulatory Quality: Percentile Rank, Lower Bound of 90% Confidence Interval", 
"Regulatory Quality: Percentile Rank, Upper Bound of 90% Confidence Interval", 
"Regulatory Quality: Standard Error", "Rule of Law: Estimate", 
"Rule of Law: Number of Sources", "Rule of Law: Percentile Rank", 
"Rule of Law: Percentile Rank, Lower Bound of 90% Confidence Interval", 
"Rule of Law: Percentile Rank, Upper Bound of 90% Confidence Interval", 
"Rule of Law: Standard Error", "Voice and Accountability: Estimate", 
"Voice and Accountability: Number of Sources", "Voice and Accountability: Percentile Rank", 
"Voice and Accountability: Percentile Rank, Lower Bound of 90% Confidence Interval", 
"Voice and Accountability: Percentile Rank, Upper Bound of 90% Confidence Interval", 
"Voice and Accountability: Standard Error"), class = "factor"), 
    Indicator.Code = structure(1:10, .Label = c("CC.EST", "CC.NO.SRC", 
    "CC.PER.RNK", "CC.PER.RNK.LOWER", "CC.PER.RNK.UPPER", "CC.STD.ERR", 
    "GE.EST", "GE.NO.SRC", "GE.PER.RNK", "GE.PER.RNK.LOWER", 
    "GE.PER.RNK.UPPER", "GE.STD.ERR", "PV.EST", "PV.NO.SRC", 
    "PV.PER.RNK", "PV.PER.RNK.LOWER", "PV.PER.RNK.UPPER", "PV.STD.ERR", 
    "RL.EST", "RL.NO.SRC", "RL.PER.RNK", "RL.PER.RNK.LOWER", 
    "RL.PER.RNK.UPPER", "RL.STD.ERR", "RQ.EST", "RQ.NO.SRC", 
    "RQ.PER.RNK", "RQ.PER.RNK.LOWER", "RQ.PER.RNK.UPPER", "RQ.STD.ERR", 
    "VA.EST", "VA.NO.SRC", "VA.PER.RNK", "VA.PER.RNK.LOWER", 
    "VA.PER.RNK.UPPER", "VA.STD.ERR"), class = "factor"), X1996 = c(-1.29170477390289, 
    2, 4.30107545852661, 0, 27.4193553924561, 0.340506970882416, 
    -2.17516660690308, 1, 0, 0), X1998 = c(-1.18084812164307, 
    2, 9.79381465911865, 0, 31.4432983398438, 0.330179065465927, 
    -2.13594222068787, 1, 0, 0), X2000 = c(-1.29537987709045, 
    2, 5.07614231109619, 0, 29.4416236877441, 0.356294184923172, 
    -2.23165082931519, 1, 0, 0), X2002 = c(-1.26336598396301, 
    2, 5.0505051612854, 0, 31.8181819915771, 0.359914720058441, 
    -1.56797313690186, 2, 2.04081630706787, 0), X2003 = c(-1.35104191303253, 
    3, 5.0505051612854, 0, 18.1818180084229, 0.275338709354401, 
    -1.08248770236969, 2, 11.7346935272217, 1.5306122303009), 
    X2004 = c(-1.34528136253357, 5, 5.85365867614746, 0, 14.1463413238525, 
    0.214314609766006, -0.894050717353821, 4, 17.2413787841797, 
    6.89655160903931), X2005 = c(-1.4436092376709, 5, 2.43902444839478, 
    0, 13.1707315444946, 0.207736045122147, -1.2108291387558, 
    4, 9.80392169952393, 1.96078431606293), X2006 = c(-1.4328898191452, 
    7, 3.90243911743164, 0, 12.1951217651367, 0.206337913870811, 
    -1.43034291267395, 6, 5.36585378646851, 0), X2007 = c(-1.58733141422272, 
    6, 0.970873773097992, 0, 7.28155326843262, 0.229119420051575, 
    -1.40335166454315, 5, 5.33980560302734, 0.485436886548996
    ), X2008 = c(-1.63828659057617, 7, 0.485436886548996, 0, 
    4.85436916351318, 0.21933402121067, -1.49608886241913, 6, 
    4.36893224716187, 0.485436886548996), X2009 = c(-1.53479599952698, 
    8, 0.956937789916992, 0, 7.65550231933594, 0.201660826802254, 
    -1.48389947414398, 7, 3.82775115966797, 0), X2010 = c(-1.63572347164154, 
    9, 0.952380955219269, 0, 3.80952382087708, 0.195554181933403, 
    -1.4546834230423, 7, 4.78468894958496, 0.478468894958496), 
    X2011 = c(-1.57917881011963, 9, 0.947867274284363, 0, 5.68720388412476, 
    0.194524049758911, -1.44848775863647, 7, 4.7393364906311, 
    0.947867274284363), X2012 = c(-1.41988801956177, 10, 2.36966824531555, 
    0, 11.8483409881592, 0.186807841062546, -1.36013960838318, 
    8, 6.63507127761841, 0.473933637142181), X2013 = c(-1.43676114082336, 
    11, 1.89573454856873, 0, 9.95260620117188, 0.160680562257767, 
    -1.38492977619171, 8, 7.5829381942749, 0.473933637142181), 
    X2014 = c(-1.35478448867798, 11, 5.28846168518066, 0.480769217014313, 
    12.5, 0.161188751459122, -1.33139562606812, 8, 8.17307662963867, 
    1.44230771064758), X2015 = c(-1.34197008609772, 11, 6.25, 
    1.44230771064758, 12.5, 0.162221297621727, -1.32298874855042, 
    8, 8.17307662963867, 1.44230771064758), X2016 = c(-1.56373512744904, 
    10, 3.36538457870483, 0, 8.65384578704834, 0.175009191036224, 
    -1.2221063375473, 8, 9.61538505554199, 4.32692289352417), 
    X = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

`filter()` & `mutate()`-Part

```
gg_stack <- dplyr::filter(gg_stack,
                          Indicator.Code %in% c("CC.EST", "GE.EST", "PV.EST", "RL.EST", "RQ.EST", "VA.EST"))

gg_stack <- gg_stack %>% 
select(-Indicator.Name,
     -X1996:-X2015,
     -X)

gg_stack <- gg_stack %>%
  mutate(
    cc2016 = case_when(Indicator.Code == "CC.EST" ~ X2016),
    ge2016 = case_when(Indicator.Code == "GE.EST" ~ X2016),
    pv2016 = case_when(Indicator.Code == "PV.EST" ~ X2016),
    rq2016 = case_when(Indicator.Code == "RQ.EST" ~ X2016),
    rl2016 = case_when(Indicator.Code == "RL.EST" ~ X2016),
    va2016 = case_when(Indicator.Code == "VA.EST" ~ X2016)
  )
dput(head(gg_stack, 10))
```

Output for `dput(head(gg_stack, 10))`

```
> dput(head(gg_stack, 10))
structure(list(Country.Name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", 
"American Samoa", "Andorra", "Angola", "Anguilla", "Antigua and Barbuda", 
"Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", 
"Bahamas, The", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", 
"Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia", 
"Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "Brunei Darussalam", 
"Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cabo Verde", "Cambodia", 
"Cameroon", "Canada", "Cayman Islands", "Central African Republic", 
"Chad", "Chile", "China", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo, Dem. Rep.", 
"Congo, Rep.", "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", "Cote d'Ivoire", 
"Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Djibouti", 
"Dominica", "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "Egypt, Arab Rep.", 
"El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia", 
"Fiji", "Finland", "France", "French Guiana", "Gabon", "Gambia, The", 
"Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", 
"Guam", "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", "Haiti", 
"Honduras", "Hong Kong SAR, China", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", 
"Indonesia", "Iran, Islamic Rep.", "Iraq", "Ireland", "Israel", 
"Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jersey, Channel Islands", "Jordan", 
"Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Korea, Dem. People’s Rep.", 
"Korea, Rep.", "Kosovo", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyz Republic", "Lao PDR", 
"Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", 
"Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macao SAR, China", "Macedonia, FYR", 
"Madagascar", "Malawi", "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", 
"Marshall Islands", "Martinique", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", 
"Mexico", "Micronesia, Fed. Sts.", "Moldova", "Monaco", "Mongolia", 
"Montenegro", "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia", 
"Nauru", "Nepal", "Netherlands", "Netherlands Antilles", "New Zealand", 
"Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Niue", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", 
"Palau", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", "Philippines", 
"Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar", "Reunion", "Romania", 
"Russian Federation", "Rwanda", "Samoa", "San Marino", "Sao Tome and Principe", 
"Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", "Serbia", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", 
"Singapore", "Slovak Republic", "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands", 
"Somalia", "South Africa", "South Sudan", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", 
"St. Kitts and Nevis", "St. Lucia", "St. Vincent and the Grenadines", 
"Sudan", "Suriname", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syrian Arab Republic", 
"Taiwan, China", "Tajikistan", "Tanzania", "Thailand", "Timor-Leste", 
"Togo", "Tonga", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey", 
"Turkmenistan", "Tuvalu", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", 
"United Kingdom", "United States", "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", 
"Venezuela, RB", "Vietnam", "Virgin Islands (U.S.)", "West Bank and Gaza", 
"Yemen, Rep.", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"), class = "factor"), Country.Code = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("ABW", "AFG", 
"AGO", "AIA", "ALB", "AND", "ANT", "ARE", "ARG", "ARM", "ASM", 
"ATG", "AUS", "AUT", "AZE", "BDI", "BEL", "BEN", "BFA", "BGD", 
"BGR", "BHR", "BHS", "BIH", "BLR", "BLZ", "BMU", "BOL", "BRA", 
"BRB", "BRN", "BTN", "BWA", "CAF", "CAN", "CHE", "CHL", "CHN", 
"CIV", "CMR", "COD", "COG", "COK", "COL", "COM", "CPV", "CRI", 
"CUB", "CYM", "CYP", "CZE", "DEU", "DJI", "DMA", "DNK", "DOM", 
"DZA", "ECU", "EGY", "ERI", "ESP", "EST", "ETH", "FIN", "FJI", 
"FRA", "FSM", "GAB", "GBR", "GEO", "GHA", "GIN", "GMB", "GNB", 
"GNQ", "GRC", "GRD", "GRL", "GTM", "GUF", "GUM", "GUY", "HKG", 
"HND", "HRV", "HTI", "HUN", "IDN", "IND", "IRL", "IRN", "IRQ", 
"ISL", "ISR", "ITA", "JAM", "JEY", "JOR", "JPN", "KAZ", "KEN", 
"KGZ", "KHM", "KIR", "KNA", "KOR", "KWT", "LAO", "LBN", "LBR", 
"LBY", "LCA", "LIE", "LKA", "LSO", "LTU", "LUX", "LVA", "MAC", 
"MAR", "MCO", "MDA", "MDG", "MDV", "MEX", "MHL", "MKD", "MLI", 
"MLT", "MMR", "MNE", "MNG", "MOZ", "MRT", "MTQ", "MUS", "MWI", 
"MYS", "NAM", "NER", "NGA", "NIC", "NIU", "NLD", "NOR", "NPL", 
"NRU", "NZL", "OMN", "PAK", "PAN", "PER", "PHL", "PLW", "PNG", 
"POL", "PRI", "PRK", "PRT", "PRY", "PSE", "QAT", "REU", "ROU", 
"RUS", "RWA", "SAU", "SDN", "SEN", "SGP", "SLB", "SLE", "SLV", 
"SMR", "SOM", "SRB", "SSD", "STP", "SUR", "SVK", "SVN", "SWE", 
"SWZ", "SYC", "SYR", "TCD", "TGO", "THA", "TJK", "TKM", "TLS", 
"TON", "TTO", "TUN", "TUR", "TUV", "TWN", "TZA", "UGA", "UKR", 
"URY", "USA", "UZB", "VCT", "VEN", "VIR", "VNM", "VUT", "WSM", 
"XKX", "YEM", "ZAF", "ZMB", "ZWE"), class = "factor"), Indicator.Code = structure(c(1L, 
7L, 13L, 25L, 19L, 31L, 1L, 7L, 13L, 25L), .Label = c("CC.EST", 
"CC.NO.SRC", "CC.PER.RNK", "CC.PER.RNK.LOWER", "CC.PER.RNK.UPPER", 
"CC.STD.ERR", "GE.EST", "GE.NO.SRC", "GE.PER.RNK", "GE.PER.RNK.LOWER", 
"GE.PER.RNK.UPPER", "GE.STD.ERR", "PV.EST", "PV.NO.SRC", "PV.PER.RNK", 
"PV.PER.RNK.LOWER", "PV.PER.RNK.UPPER", "PV.STD.ERR", "RL.EST", 
"RL.NO.SRC", "RL.PER.RNK", "RL.PER.RNK.LOWER", "RL.PER.RNK.UPPER", 
"RL.STD.ERR", "RQ.EST", "RQ.NO.SRC", "RQ.PER.RNK", "RQ.PER.RNK.LOWER", 
"RQ.PER.RNK.UPPER", "RQ.STD.ERR", "VA.EST", "VA.NO.SRC", "VA.PER.RNK", 
"VA.PER.RNK.LOWER", "VA.PER.RNK.UPPER", "VA.STD.ERR"), class = "factor"), 
    X2016 = c(-1.56373512744904, -1.2221063375473, -2.74916744232178, 
    -1.32791936397552, -1.61642956733704, -1.08621954917908, 
    -0.397567093372345, -0.000573236728087068, 0.257720142602921, 
    0.188962236046791), cc2016 = c(-1.56373512744904, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, -0.397567093372345, NA, NA, NA), ge2016 = c(NA, 
    -1.2221063375473, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.000573236728087068, 
    NA, NA), pv2016 = c(NA, NA, -2.74916744232178, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 0.257720142602921, NA), rq2016 = c(NA, NA, NA, -1.32791936397552, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.188962236046791), rl2016 = c(NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, -1.61642956733704, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), va2016 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, -1.08621954917908, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

At the end I get this data.frame:

```
> str(gg_stack)
'data.frame':   1284 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ Country.Name  : Factor w/ 214 levels "Afghanistan",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Country.Code  : Factor w/ 214 levels "ABW","AFG","AGO",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ Indicator.Code: Factor w/ 36 levels "CC.EST","CC.NO.SRC",..: 1 7 13 25 19 31 1 7 13 25 ...
 $ X2016         : num  -1.56 -1.22 -2.75 -1.33 -1.62 ...
 $ cc2016        : num  -1.56 NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ge2016        : num  NA -1.22 NA NA NA ...
 $ pv2016        : num  NA NA -2.75 NA NA ...
 $ rq2016        : num  NA NA NA -1.33 NA ...
 $ rl2016        : num  NA NA NA NA -1.62 ...
 $ va2016        : num  NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

As you see, I got for each country 6 rows. For every indicator-column is now a sperate row. For the indicator cc2016 I got the value in the first row, the next five rows are NA's. So, how can I compress my data.frame into a format like this one (every indicator-coloumn gets the same row):

```
 $ X2016         : num  -1.56 -1.22 -2.75 -1.33 -1.62 ...
 $ cc2016        : num  -1.56 ...
 $ ge2016        : num  -1.22 ...
 $ pv2016        : num  -2.75 ...
 $ rq2016        : num  -1.33 ...
 $ rl2016        : num  -1.62 ...
 $ va2016        : num   ...
```

Do I need to change the code in the mutate-part? I really hope you get my problem.

Comment: Far from a complete answer, just a comment or two: 1) `read.csv` defaults to `sep = ","`, yours is a *frequent but redundant* practice; 2) `Indicator.Code == "CC.EST"` or `"GE.EST"`or etc should become just one code line `Indicator.Code %in% c("CC.EST", "GE.EST", etc)`.

Comment: 3) In the `select` you can do `-X2002:X2015`. Another 14 (!) code lines simplified. Even better, `select(..., -num_range("X", c(1996, 1998, 2000, 2002:2015))`.

Comment: Finally, can you edit **the question** with the output of `dput(head(gg_stack, 10))`, please?

Comment: Done.

And thanks for the tips.

Comment: What you posted is (very) usefull but it's the expected output, we also need the input. Run the same `dput` command but right after reading the data in, and post it in the question, please. If you can, write something like "Input" and "Expected output" before each dataset.

Comment: I run the `dput`command right after the `read.csv` command. I hope that helps as well.